# whenever i try running an app on Android studio 3.6. it brings this error... how can i fix this so that my apps can run in an emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.6

[enter image description here] FAILURE:Build failed with an exception

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE78D.jpg What went wrong

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) - post as text here to make it findable by others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the offline mode of Gradle by going to File - Project Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle - Remove --offline in Command Line options.(Or, simply click the -//- icon in the Gradle window.)

Then, connect to the internet and run Gradle build.

After the build has run once, you can enable the offline mode again.